# Is a position located (surrounded) within the html of a button or tag (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

What is the most efficient way to check if a particular position (index) is within a button or link?

example1: position 146 not inside vs position 89 that is inside

```
this is not inside a link<a href="temp.com"><span class="span1"><span class="span2">linkTextInside</span></span></a>not inside<p class="temp2">not inside</p>
```

example2:

```
not inside<button><span>buttontextInside</span></button>not inside
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put node.js as a tag, I suppose you are treating the html file content as a string on the server side. In the client I suppose you would use the parentNode to find this out.

```
let text = 'this is not inside a link<a href="temp.com"><span class="span1"><span class="span2">linkTextInside</span></span></a>not inside<p class="temp2">not inside</p>'
let startposition = text.search(/<a|<button/g);
let endposition = text.search(/<\/a>|<\/button>/g);
let x = 89;
let y = 146;

function inBetween(startPosition, endPosition, number) {
    if (number > startposition && number < endposition) {
      return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(inBetween(startposition , endposition, x)); // true
console.log(inBetween(startposition , endposition, y)); // false
```